# Добавление областей и линий на график из фрейма данных

Tags: python, pandas

Мне требуется нарисовать диаграмму Парето. Делаю это следующим образом:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"Вид дефекта":["А","Б","В","Г","Д","Е","Ж","Прочее"], "Кол-во":[11,2,333,4,15,6,777,8]})
data=data.set_index("Вид дефекта")
data = pd.concat([data[data.index!='Прочее'].sort_values(by='Кол-во',ascending = False), data[data.index=='Прочее']])
data['Накопленная частота'] = 100 *data['Кол-во'].cumsum() / data['Кол-во'].sum()
fig, axes = plt.subplots()
ax1 = data.plot(use_index=True, y='Кол-во',  kind='bar', ax=axes)
ax2 = data.plot(use_index=True, y='Накопленная частота', marker='D', color="C1", kind='line', ax=axes, secondary_y=True)
ax2.set_ylim([0,110])
```

Получаю следующий рисунок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако к этой диаграмме мне требуется добавить два элемента — горизонтальную пунктирную линию и область принятия решений.
Где пунктирная линия = на уровне 80% по шкале справа (ax2)
А в область принятия решений попадают все значения, где накопленная частота<80% следующая за последним

Пример-как это должно быть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для решения задачи дописала следующее:

```
data['Порог']=80
data['Область принятия решений']=np.where((data['Порог'] <= data['Накопленная частота']) & (data['Порог'].shift(1) <= data['Накопленная частота'].shift(1)), 0, 100)
```

Подскажите, как теперь это добавить на тот же график

Comment: Это вообще из какой области вопрос-то? Оптимизация или даже менеджмент, судя по всему, более, чем программирование. Тогда пунктирную автоматически на 80% всегда, раз уж это Парето, да и для области принятия решений алгоритм должен быть, полагаю, исходя из вводимых данных?  Тогда - опирайтесь на dataframe, рассчитывайте Парето-оптимальное множество и т.д. Но я бы на вашем месте внимательно задачу перечитал или спросил того, кто вам её поставил. А то будет смешно неделю  на оптимизацию убить, если она не нужна.

Comment: на всякий случай: про "автоматически на 80%" тоже лучше уточнить. Не удивлюсь, если эта величина  тоже расчетной окажется. 80% - всё же эмпирика.

Comment: @Сергей Спасибо за ваш комментарий! Конкретно здесь 80% - константа. Пунктирная получилась автоматически (просто привязалась к y=80), а для области принятия решения алгоритм такой: в неё попадают все те, где накопленная частота<80% следующая за последним

Comment: @Сергей выражаясь языком екселя =ЕСЛИ(И(D5>=E5;D4>=E4);0;100)
но как это перенести в пандас, я не знаю (тк нужно учитывать предыдущую строку)

Comment: ОксанаЮ, тогда советую переформулировать вопрос прямо в его теле.

Answer (score 0):

Я только не смог с легендой доразобраться, как её подвинуть, чтобы нормально было видно:

```py
ax3 = data.plot(use_index=True, y='Порог', color="gray", kind='line', linestyle='dashed', ax=axes, secondary_y=True)
ax4 = data.plot(use_index=True, y='Область принятия решений', color="yellow", kind='area', ax=axes, secondary_y=True, alpha=0.1)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ! Тоже пробовала вид  'area', к сожалению, он делает правую сторону скошенной, а мне требуется ровная (как на примере)

Comment: Да, я это заметил, мне казалось это как-то решается, но как - не могу вспомнить